# Why is BayazitDecomposer inaccessible when upgrading from Farseer 3.3.1 to Farseer 3.5?

Tags: xna, c#, farseer-physics-engine

I used the following code in Farseer 3.3.1 and it worked correctly, but in Farseer 3.5, I always get an error message in the following line:

```
list = BayazitDecomposer.ConvexPartition(textureVertices);
'FarseerPhysics.Common.Decomposition.BayazitDecomposer' is inaccessible due to its protection level
```

What is wrong? Why is the code not working with Farseer 3.5? How can I use the decomposition tools in Farseer 3.5?

Comment: I solved the problem. I changed the line to: list = Triangulate.ConvexPartition(textureVertices, TriangulationAlgorithm.Bayazit);

Answer (score 1):

The `BayazitDecomposer` was made assembly-internal in commit 101497, which was aimed at centralizing the input validation for the triangulation algorithms in a single place according to the check-in comment:

> Removed sanity checks from all triangulators and moved them into
> Triangulate. Added asserts into each triangulation algorithm that
> checks if the polygon is valid. Triangulator is a new class that does
> all the work of validating inputs and sanatizing outputs.

Per that comment, one is now expected to use the `ConvexPartition` method from the `Triangulate` class, passing an enumeration value to specify the desired triangulation algorithm (as you noted, the value you want to use for a Bayazit implementation is `TriangulationAlgorithm.Bayazit`).

---

The original links will be unavaiable pending the closure of CodePlex.

Farseer Physics has been superseded by [Velcro Physic](https://github.com/Genbox/VelcroPhysics) and its implementation of `BayazitDecomposer` can be found [here](https://github.com/Genbox/VelcroPhysics/blob/master/src/VelcroPhysics/Tools/Triangulation/Bayazit/BayazitDecomposer.cs).